# C# UWP The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp

I have a C# UWP app that contains a function I want to call every 5 seconds.
The function runs fine when called from a button, and the Timer write to the debug console fine every 5 seconds....When I call the function from the Timer, all heck breaks loose. I get this:

System.Exception was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147417842
Message=The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Comment: What kind of Timer are you using?

Answer (score 14):

I assume your function touches the app's UI. Anything which touches the UI needs to run on the UI's dispatcher thread (most apps will have only one until you get into multiple window apps).

You can use a Windows.UI.Xaml.[DispatcherTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx) to run your timer on the dispatcher thread.

If you need to run code on a worker thread and then touch UI on the dispatcher thread you can call Dispatcher.[RunAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync.aspx) to marshal a call back onto the dispatcher thread.

You can generally find your dispatcher from your Window via [Window.Dispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.window.dispatcher.aspx).

```
var ignored = Window.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
   // Do something on the dispatcher thread
});
```

Comment: If you have a container other than a window, or your entire process is off-UI thread: `container.Dispatcher.RunAsync(...)` is a better bet. You can store this for later use, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are using a `Timer` from `System.Threading`. That timer's events are not treated like a regular GUI event and if you are accessing a GUI item form the method invoked by that timer, it will cause issues since that thread is not the owner of the GUI item.

Use a `Timer` from `System.Windows.Forms`. That timer has access to your GUI items.

Comment: Correct in principle but System.Windows.Forms in an UWP app seems unlikely.

Comment: @spender You mean it is not available in UWP?

Answer (score 1):

You could actually use [Observable.Interval from Reactive Extensions](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) and specify explicitly on which dispatcher you want to observe timer events:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.Default)
    .ObserveOn(coreWindow.Dispatcher)
    .Subscribe(_ => Log.Warning("Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess: " + coreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess));
```

What I like about this approach is that you explicitly stating what happens on which thread (see [SubscribeOn and ObserveOn](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html)).